# What percentage of Himeji castle keep remains original...?

Tags: japan, architecture, castles

Recently I've visited the [castle in Matsue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsue_Castle), acknowledged as one of twelve remaining Japanese castles with their original keep preserved. There I've learnt that during the Shōwa period it went through a long renovation. The entire keep was dismantled and then rebuilt. Workers tried their best to reuse as much of original material as possible but most of it deteriorated and needed to be replaced. According to the exhibition it's estimated that only 40% of material used remained original.

I know that [Himeji castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himeji_Castle), the most famous of the twelve, was treated similarly. According to the [Shōwa era restoration document](https://www.mlit.go.jp/tagengo-db/en/R1-00680.html)

> The most extensive repair work in the history of Himeji Castle began
> in 1956 and lasted almost eight years. Known as the Shōwa-era
> Restoration, after the Shōwa imperial era (1926–1989), this massive
> project involved the complete dismantling and reassembly of the main
> keep.
>
> Many historical and architectural discoveries were made along the way,
> thanks to inscriptions left on parts of the structure by its original
> builders. From 1956 to 1958, the entire keep was dismantled under a
> giant roofed scaffold. Workers then spent several years cleaning,
> repairing, and—where necessary—replacing the building’s posts, beams,
> and other components, before painstakingly reassembling the entire
> structure. The small adjoining keeps, connecting galleries, and
> kitchen were repaired as well. By the end of the project in 1964, the
> equivalent of over 250,000 working-days had been spent on the project.

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himeji_Castle) mentions following information:

> The main keep has two pillars, with one standing in the east and one
> standing in the west. The east pillar, which has a base diameter of 97
> cm (38 in), was originally a single fir tree, but it has since been
> mostly replaced. The base of the west pillar is 85 by 95 cm (33 by 37
> in), and it is made of Japanese cypress. During the Shōwa Restoration
> (1956–1964) a Japanese cypress tree with a length of 26.4 m (87 ft)
> was brought down from the Kiso Mountains and replaced the old pillar.
> The tree was broken in this process, so another tree was brought down
> from Mount Kasagata, and the two trees were joined on the third floor.

What I am interested is the scale of these changes. Were they as big as in the case of Matsue castle...? The information about Shōwa restoration seems scarce and I couldn't pinpoint an exact number. Many places (such as aforementioned Wikipedia article) refer to the castle as "intact", which is somewhat baffling given that it's at least partially reconstructed.

So my question is: what is an estimated percentage of post Meiji replacement material? How much of it actually dates all the way back to shōgun times...?

Comment: Trees carrying load have the tendency to disintegrate. Unless they are separated from cycles of saturation/desaturation and hot/cold, like the submerged part in the mud part of the pillars of pile-dwellings.